# Javascript templete literals not working with random number generator

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to generate a random number and then if the user enters the same num he can move forward otherwise it will generate another random number. But the template literal to generate random num (a) is not working.

```
var a = Math.floor(Math.random()*10); // Random num generator
    var userInput = alert('Enter the numbers: ${a}'); // User input
    
    while ( userInput !== a){ // Loop
        alert("Try Again!");
        userInput = alert('Enter the numbers: ${a}');
    };
```

Comment: Literals work with the tick "`" character

Comment: The `alert()` function returns `undefined` always. So it will never equal a number whatever that number is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that can be improved in your code.

- Naming your number variable `a` instead of `n` is confusing.
- `Math.floor` can be shorted to `~~` in your case (not every case).
- You get user input from `prompt`, not `alert`, which merely shows a message.
- You're using the strict equality `!==` operator to compare your random number with the user's input, which will always be a number in `String` form.  So even if they enter the correct number, it will be interpreted as incorrect, since `'3'` is not strictly equal to `3`.  You have to use `!=` instead.
- There's no need for a `userInput` variable since you're only doing one thing with it.  Just inline the `prompt` inside the condition of the `while` loop.
- Since `n` never changes, declare it with `const` so that if you accidentally try to change it later, you will get an error to bring this to your attention.
- As someone noted in the comments, string literals use `` ` ``, not `'`.

```js
const n = ~~(Math.random() * 10);
while (prompt(`Enter the number: ${n}`) != n) {
  alert('Try again!');
};
```